# Maps and strings in Drools rules

Tags: java, drools, business-rules

I have following Drools rule to which I send map filled with element , but when it gets executed I have element . Why do I get null when it should be "Y" for the value? When I put breakpoint in ACDebug.debug() method and inspect map after $map.put() was executed it looks good, it has "Y" for the value, but after my rules get executed I have null? Has anyone have similar problem?

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import edu.abc.ACDebug;

rule "POSTPROCESSOR 8"
    ruleflow-group "supress-processor"
    when
        $map:Map(keySet contains "STANDARD_ADDRESS:STREET_NAME")
    then
        ACDebug.debug($map, "Map before PUT: ");
        $map.put("/locationList/sourceAddress/fullStreet",new String("Y"));
        ACDebug.debug($map, "Map after PUT: ");
        $map.remove("STANDARD_ADDRESS:STREET_NAME");
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you have done the changes to the map, you need to do an update. This lets the working memory know that you modified the map.

Add the following line:

```
update( $map );
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. I saw examples without call of update() and I tought it will always work.